ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED virtual host apache 2.4 mac ventura
I have multiple virtual hosts set up on macOS Ventura 13.7. It's been a few years since I set this up, and now I need to spin up and develop a new site. Either my system isn't configured correctly anymore, or I have forgotten the steps. I want to be able to open and run any of my websites (html or php) on my local machine.
Configuration
/etc/hosts has
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   mysite1.com
127.0.0.1   mysite2.com
127.0.0.1   mysite3.com
127.0.0.1   mysite4.com
127.0.0.1   mysite5.cc
127.0.0.1   mysite6.com
127.0.0.1   mysite7.com
127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal
# kubernetes added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
# End of section


/etc/apache2/httpd.conf has
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfDefine SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 8080
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 80
</IfDefine>

ServerName localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites"
<Directory "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf has
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite1.com
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/mysite1"
    ServerName localmysite1.com
    ServerAlias www.localmysite1.com
    ErrorLog "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/apache_logs/localmysite1/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/apache_logs/localmysite1/logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite2.com
    DocumentRoot "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/mysite2"
    ServerName localmysite2.com
    ServerAlias www.localmysite2.com
    ErrorLog "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/apache_logs/localmysite2/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/Volumes/HD/Web/websites/apache_logs/localmysite2/logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
...

Problem
mysite5.cc shows an html page that resides in /Volumes/HD/Web/websites. It's functioning as if I have the browser pointed to 127.0.0.1 or localhost:80. I don't see why this site behaves differently.
I was able to open each of the other sites in Chrome exactly once. After closing the tab I can no longer access any of them, even if restart Apache. I see this error
This site can’t be reached
mysite1.com refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is the same error I get if I point my browser to localhost:8080.
Troubleshooting
Restarting Apache doesn't help. Restarting the computer didn't help either.
apachectl configtest returns Syntax OK
I tried flushing the DNS cache with
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
I tried changing Listen 80 to Listen 8080 and vice-versa. Interestingly, this does not change what I see in the browser. localhost:80 always shows the page in the DocumentRoot. I can see the initial view of each site in the access logs. There are no errors recorded.
Comparing to similar posts here, I tried this:
↪ curl -I -L 127.0.0.1 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2024 06:46:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.59 (Unix) PHP/8.3.4
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Feb 2024 21:51:14 GMT
ETag: "22-6110e0b1e1880"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 34

nslookup mysite1.com
** server can't find mysite1.com: NXDOMAIN

httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.59 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  3 2024 12:22:45

which httpd
/usr/local/bin/httpd

php -v
PHP 8.3.4 (cli) (built: Mar 12 2024 23:42:26) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.4, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.4, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

which php
/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php

I use sudo apachectl start to start apache.
The above lead me to think I've got another instance of apache installed. Turns out I do. I must have installed Apache from Homebrew at some point. In /usr/local/etc/httpd I found a copy of httpd.conf and /extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. I don't see a brew version of the hosts file.
File comparisons revealed that the Homebrew version of httpd.conf contains Listen 127.0.0.1:80. I changed this to Listen *:80. Now when I visit mysite5.cc, a php file downloads to my desktop. At least that's better than showing the wrong page. I need to remember out how to launch php...
Strangely, when I visit the other sites I still see the connection error. So I still have some configuration issues.

Hosts entries are not DNS records so using tools like nslookup and dig are not the right ones to debug issues. In addition It might be that the site/domain sets security headers enforcing secure access, like HSTS  and/or a permanent redirect to https , both of which are cached by your browser. Your browser will then refuse to connect over clear text http and you should setup a TLS certificate or test from a new anonymous window

Thanks for the suggestion. I created an SSL certificate for local development (following these steps https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/). Unfortunately, I still see the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error message in Chrome. Opening the page in an Incognito window doesn't help either, sadly. By the way, do you know if I need to create a separate cert for each dev site? I'm thinking I could probably just point each of the VirtualHosts to the same cert.
